# Why this regular expression gets true in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I was started learning the regular expressions in ruby. In that I had one problem. The problem is the below regular expression does not work as expected.

```
/^[\s]*$/  -- This will match only if the input contains white spaces or the input contains empty.
```

For example,

```
str = "      

        abc

            "
if str =~ /^[\s]*$/
        puts "Condition is true"
else
        puts "Condition is false"
end
```

My expectation is this condition will gets false. But it gets true. I don't know why ?

In sed or grep it will work as expected. But why it does not works in ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that in Ruby regex, `^` and `$` match the start/end of a *line*. Change to `\A` and `\z` and you will get a `false` result.

See [this Ruby demo at Ideone](https://ideone.com/G9ws8d). The `/\A\s*\z/` will only match *strings* that are either empty or have whitespace symbols only.

As for `\s`, it is a synonym for `[ \t\r\n\f]`, not just `[ \t\n]`. See this [Ruby Character Class reference](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes):

> `/\s/` - A whitespace character: `/[ \t\r\n\f]/`

Comment: That's true and a real source of annoyance but the actual issue is `[\s]` instead of `\s`.

Comment: @cremno: Where did you get `[\s*]`? I checked the post history, OP never had that pattern. Please let me know if I should explain anything else, or if everything is clear.

Comment: Just a typo. grep and sed are line based. `^` / `$` work the same way as in Ruby. But grep's `[\s]` is equivalent to Ruby's `[\\s]`.

Comment: Oh, if you do not use `-P` (PCRE) option with `grep`, you cannot use shorthand character classes inside bracket expressions, they are parsed as literal symbol combinations. That is a completely different story since regex engines are of different flavors. Note that Ruby uses [Oniguruma regex flavor](https://github.com/geoffgarside/oniguruma/blob/master/Syntax.txt).